# A PHP script (form 'action' attribute) always returns 404

Tags: php, post, http-status-code-404

I've come accross this strange problem where sending a POST request to my custom PHP script always returns 404 - a script file not found.

I find it strange because the same code is present on three different servers. Two of them process the request as expected, the third one always returns 404.

This is the form tag:

```
<form action="<?php echo SITE_URL ?>/web/advertisers-cats-action.php" ..
```

File permissions are the same across all three servers. The script in questiosn is `-rw-rw-r--`, "." and ".." are `drwxr-xr-x` so that the browser can navigate between fodlers

When I get the 404 error, the path to the script is correct. It points exactly to the script where it is on the server.

I can navigate to the parent directory of the script in the browser. Then I see the script being listed with other files. When I click on the file (not submitting a POST request, but GET this time - just clicking on it), I get 404.

This is the case only on one of the three servers.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Check source of your page and see what you find in action attr

Comment: @vps I've just checked the source, the URL of the action attribute is correct.

Comment: Is the server in question hosted with different security policies? See [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: can you access that url directly using browser?

Comment: any rewrites or other .htaccess-related stuff in that folder?

Comment: @vps I cannot access the script directly from the browser - it returns 404. I can, however, access the directory itself without a problem where is see the sctipt file listed.

Comment: @jossif no .htaccess stuff in the folder. Thi is a Wordpress site and there is only one .htaccess at the root of the WP install. It is standard WP .htaccess

Comment: If its Wordpress then where do you have this `/web/advertisers-cats-action.php` ?

Comment: @vps `http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/MyPlugin/web/advertisers-cats-action.php` - This is how the form action attribute is resolved, and this is where the script file lives

Answer (score 0):

You  have missing semicolon  and  syntax  errors,you  have to use

"echo site_url(); "

Comment: `SITE_URL` is a constant, not a function. You're actually correct that a semicolon should be there. However, inspecting the source of the page, I can see the correct URL in the `action` attribute of the form. This makes me think that this is not the cause of the probelm.

Comment: Inline PHP like this does not require a semicolon.